# Ignore create/change of model for a SQL View using Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-view

If I create a SQL view and write a model to represent that view I will still want it to map up to be able to read data from the SQL view. The Add-Migration code will see this as a new table because entity framework (version 6) doesn't understand views.

Is there an attribute that I could assign that would prevent migration code from thinking its a new table it needs to create or something in the model builder?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mapping Database Views to EF 5.0 Code First w/Migrations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862807/mapping-database-views-to-ef-5-0-code-first-w-migrations)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, I know that I can use the up/down code to control the migration but I would like future instances of migration code to not evaluate certain models (because the represent already created views) by means of an attribute like the suggestion from @Mashton below.

Answer (score 2):

add migration nomaly. and after migration rewrite to:

```
public override void Up()
{
    Sql("CREATE VIEW [viewname] AS SELECT {any select expression} ");
}

public override void Down()
{
    Sql("DROP VIEW [viewname]");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9623319/188926):

```
Add-Migration IgnoreViewClasses –IgnoreChanges
```

(Works for EF 4.3.1+)

This creates an empty migration, ignoring any newly created classes from now on.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [NotMapped] attribute to stop code-first classes being migrated into database creation.

Comment: NotMapped would cause the property to not link to the column in the table it represents which is not the desired goal in this case.