# How to exclude one table from automatic code first migrations in the Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using the Entity Framework in the Code First mode with automatic migrations enabled. Now, I have one entity whose table should *not* be managed (migrated) by the EF. Is there a way of disabling automatic migrations for one specific entity (i.e. table)?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

This is now possible in EF Core 5.0 using the `ExcludeFromMigrations()` method, but strangely enough you have to call the `ToTable()` method and then use the `TableBuilder`.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-core-efcore-5-0-rc1/#exclude-tables-from-migrations

```cs
public class ReportingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable(nameof(Users), t => t.ExcludeFromMigrations());
    }
}
```

Comment: This method also works with EF Core 6.

Answer (score 45):

Another option that worked for me in EFCore 5.0 is to use [SetIsTableExcludedFromMigrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalentitytypeextensions.setistableexcludedfrommigrations?view=efcore-5.0):

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Metadata.SetIsTableExcludedFromMigrations(true);
}
```

Comment: How is your answer different than the currently most voted on?

Comment: With this method, you don't need to know the table name, which may or may not be `nameof(Users)`

Answer (score 12):

My TEMPORARY solution, only for dev environments. 
I have a separate script that runs migration and program run does not check them. So in unexpected case I was possible to invoke `Ignore<ContactView>()` and run migrations with this line. When it was completed, I removed this line!

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // comment out this code after migrations are done
        modelBuilder.Ignore<ContactView>();
    }
```

Comment: You could use a compiler, preprocessor directive

E.g: #define DEVELOPING

And when set, your code block gets included

#If DEVELOPING
modelBuilder.Ignore<ContactView>();
#endif

Of course, you could use the built in directive DEBUG

#If DEBUG
modelBuilder.Ignore<ContactView>();
#endif
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if

Comment: @AntonyBooth - in this case, it was really a "one timer". But yeah, if project policy allows it, preprocessor directives could be a way to go.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible by using another `DbContext` to access the table in question. Migrations are bound to one `DbContext` (see [Is it possible to have automatic migrations for one DbContext and not for another in the same project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22154381/is-it-possible-to-have-automatic-migrations-for-one-dbcontext-and-not-for-anothe)).

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this is the OP's exact scenario, but I had a table that I did not want a migration generated for. I accomplished this by using `ToView` instead of `ToTable` within the DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>(entity => {
        // Migration will not be generated for this table
        entity.ToView("MyTable", "dbo");

        entity.Property(e => e.FooBar).HasColumnType("DECIMAL(19,9)");
    });
}
```

It feels a bit hacky to me, but maybe it's not -- because, after all, I'm just trying to "view" the table, not write to it...

[Tested with .NET Core EF 3.1.3]

*** update 06/17/23: the above solution is still viable if you are stuck working with EF3, but if you are using EF5+ you should use the new `ExcludeFromMigrations()` function: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-core-efcore-5-0-rc1/#exclude-tables-from-migrations

Comment: This method has a big problem with EF 5. If you define a table as view, then if you have any foreign key to this table it won't make them! I tested the method of @Tobias and that works in EF5

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the `[NotMapped]` annotation on that class/entity.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. I get an InvalidOperationException saying "The type '...' was not mapped..." when I try to execute a query on the corresponding DbSet.

Comment: Ah ok, so you still want it in your model but not under the control of migrations. In that case, you'll want something like this ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016709/how-to-ignore-a-table-class-in-ef-4-3-migrations

Comment: exactly. However, the answer you are referring to works only if you have an existing schema and then decide that EF should take control over it. In my case, I want EF to *never* touch that particular table. The schema of that table will evolve through the time but outside EF.

Comment: Time for me to bow out - that's my knowledge of EF migrations stretched beyond breaking point! Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

The question mentions (one table) but I had this problem with the view model. when you properly an SQL view in an SQL database and a model of it in your project, So maybe you do not need to add migration in your project coz of this view. The solution is to ignore write DbSet in your DataBaseContext and only configure it by fluentApi config or ComponentModel.DataAnnotations