# Is it possible to have automatic migrations for one DbContext and not for another in the same project?

Tags: entity-framework

I would like to have two DbContexts in the same project but automatic migrations enabled only for one. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

It is. Each `DbMigrationsConfiguration` is bound to one specific `DbContext` via `ContextKey`. As soon as you have more than on `DbContext`, the `Enable-Migrations` command requires the `-ContextTypeName` parameter. One can easily just run `Enable-Migrations` for one DbContext and omit it for the other.