# Entity framework core multipleDbContext code-first migration of shared entity

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using mutiple dbContext (IdentityDbContext and DBContext) in my app.
Due to some reasons, I am bound to use multiple DBContext, as I know you will answer me to Use only DBContext as inherit DBContext from IdentityDbContext (I will not do this).

Anyhow, I have a table named Patient in DBContext, which has Foreign key relation with User. and User belongs to IdentityDBContext.

Now when I am generating Migration scripts from DBContext, It adds DDL for User; Although User table is already created during IdentityDBContext migration. 
It seems, there is something missing in migration relation. I want to create foreign key Patient.UserId ==> User.UserId, but don't create User table ddl scripts.

Can anyone help me how to define such relationship between two entities that are defined in another DBContext.

Comment: Which store are you using? If SQL Server or similar you can create a DB link between the two and setup a view so you can actually map the object to your context.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038924/how-to-exclude-one-table-from-automatic-code-first-migrations-in-the-entity-fram

Comment: Thanks @Fenixil. I checked the suggested solution, but it didn't worked for me. i.e. Ignore will also ignore the foreign key and the second suggestion to disable migration for a while is not answer in my case

Comment: Thank @jcruz. I am using SQL Server. Can you please explain how DB link between DB context will help me. I never applied DB link in EF. let me check if it can solve my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround here is to create migration and comment generated code(similar to previous EF version -IgnoreChanges switch). Apply migration that in the end changes nothing, but keeps track of current `DbContext` model snapshot and will never generate code again.

The downside is that you need to do such a step everytime you change `IdentityDbContext` and apply new migration.