# EF Core has two DbContexts. How do I specify the tables?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two `DbContext`s in the database and want to make one of them only reference the one table (class):

```
dotnet ef migrations add Mall20200325 --context ApplicationDbContext
```

And in the `ApplicationDbContext` there is only one DbSet:

```
public DbSet<Models.User> Users { get; set; }
```

But it will still migrate other tables.

How to do I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you’re looking for? Am I to understand that you want your two separate DbContexts, each mapped to a separate table? But you want to ensure other tables are still created as part of the migration, even though they’re not mapped to a DbContext? (I may well be misunderstanding; I’m extrapolating a bit.)

Comment: @JeremyCaney thank you . I want the tables not mapped in the DbContext will not be migrated.

Comment: If I use dotnete ef migrations add xxx ---conntext ApplicationDbContext.. some table not mapped in the ApplicationDbContext also have migrated. but they are mapped in another DbContext. I want to these tables are seperate.

Comment: If you have other entities as navigation property in `Users`, then they are indirectly mapped by the datacontext. You'll have to either [Ignore](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/ignore-method) those fields or include them in your context anyway.

Comment: @MatJ. No,The Users is only mapped in ApplicationDbContext.Other tables such as Orders is in anther DbContext.But when I migrate the ApplicationDbContext it will also migrate the other tables including Orders. but it is not mapped in ApplicationDbContext

Comment: Include the User class definition in your question. Are you sure your User class does not have any property with type `Orders` or such?

Comment: @MatJ yes there is .It is my fault. and I use modelBuidler.Ignore with all other tables .

Answer (score 0):

your problem its than you are using two -- instead one

dotnet ef migrations add Mall20200325 -context ApplicationDbContext

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038924/how-to-exclude-one-table-from-automatic-code-first-migrations-in-the-entity-fram). Assume you have `AccountDbContext` and `ApplicationDbContext` contexts. Assume in the `AccountDbContext` the entity `Account` has been defined and we want to exclude `accounts` table from migration, while we have a reference to it in the `User` entity. Therefore:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Ignored table `accounts` from other DbContext in the migration

    modelBuilder.Entity<Account>(entity => {
        entity.ToView("accounts");
        // If the `acoounts` table has some columns you must introduce their
        // names like this (if the properties' names are different from columns' names)    
        entity.Property(e => e.Id)
              .HasColumnName("id");
        entity.Property(e => e.FirstName)
              .HasColumnName("first_name");
        entity.Property(e => e.LastName)
              .HasColumnName("last_name");
    });
    
    // Define the table `users`

    modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity => {
        entity.ToTable("users");

        entity.HasIndex(e => e.Id)
           .HasName("users_account_id_foreign");

        entity.Property(e => e.Id)
           .HasColumnName("id")
           .HasColumnType("bigint(20) unsigned");

       entity.HasOne(d => d.Account)
           .WithOne(p => p.Users)
           .HasForeignKey<User>(d => d.Id)
           .HasConstraintName("users_account_id_foreign");
        
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Add-Migration process compares two `IModel` instances, one from your context's `OnModelCreating` the other compiled into your assembly and loaded from the `IMigrationsAssembly` service.

The MigrationsAssembly implementation should only consider model snapshots and migrations with a matching `DbContextAttribute`.

If you are seeing migration operations that you didn't expect, then I have to wonder what your project looked like before you created two contexts. Do you have a generated `ModelSnapshot`, with a mismatched `[DbContext]` attribute?