# Entity Framework Core 3, Define DBSet for query but dont create migration entry

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

Within EF core 3.1, I am trying to run some custom SQL as a test, to see if I can populate a custom object. My custom object is called **CustomPerson**.

```
public partial class CustomPerson
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

The code to run the SQL is as follows:

```
public List<CustomPerson> GetCustomPersonSql()
{
    var persons = _context.CustomPerson.FromSqlRaw("SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Person");
    return persons.ToList();
}
```

I have declared it as follows in the Context file, note the HasNoKey().

```
public DbSet<CustomPerson> CustomPerson { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
     modelBuilder.Entity<CustomPerson>(entity =>
     {
          entity.HasNoKey();
     });
}
```

This works and returns the data, but when I run the following migration to check if it thinks anything has changed.

```
Add-Migration anythingNew
```

It creates the **CustomPerson** table! which I don't want. This needs to be a query only object and not stored or added to the database.

I have tried the following instead in the OnModelCreating, but this then stops the query from working.

```
modelBuilder.Ignore<CustomPerson>();
```

Can anyone help me get this working. So I want it to be used to query custom SQL responses, but not be included in any migrations?

Comment: You could remove everything related to that "entity" from the generated migration's `Up()` and `Down()` and it will cause no problems at runtime. Migrations are not sacrosanct. Also, what does doing `modelBuilder.Entity<CustomPerson>().ToQuery("query")` produce in the migration?

Comment: Ok, it felt like the migrations were very important and tied heavily to everything, which I don't really like. We currently use fluent migrator which seems a lot easier, Database first which I prefer :)
Im not sure how to use ToQuery that syntax is not supported with a string

Comment: Similar question answer in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038924/how-to-exclude-one-table-from-automatic-code-first-migrations-in-the-entity-fram

Comment: Posting comment as answer too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this working by appending the .ToView on the end as shown below

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CustomPerson>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasNoKey()
          .ToView(null);
});
```

So the **HasNoKey** seems to allow me to use it such as this

```
var persons = _context.CustomPerson.FromSqlRaw("SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Person");
return persons.ToList();
```

Then the **ToView** makes sure to ignore it if you create a migration

If I do try and use this as someone mentioned

```
modelBuilder.Ignore<CustomPerson>();
```

then I don't get the migration, but I cant use the object as a domain object then! as it blows up when I do the SELECT and try and pull it back as my object.

Comment: That's a pretty weird, but apparently valid, usecase for `ToView()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove everything related to that "entity" from the generated migration's Up() and Down() and it will cause no problems at runtime.

Migrations are not sacrosanct, or black magic. It is advisable to always go through the migrations that EF generates and make any modifications as needed. For instance, you could modify all foreign key constraints with a `NO CHECK` in SQL server to leave your FKs as documentation only.