# EF Core - can migrations in multiple contexts use same ContextModelSnapshot file

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I am using EF Core on .NET 6 with a code-first approach.

I want to have two contexts that connect to the same database. I want them each to have an `Items` property.

However, in one of them the `Items` property is mapped to the table in the database in one zone, while in the other in the other zone. E.g. `zone1.Items` and `zone2.Items`.

The tables have different columns.

So I have `Context1` defined as:

```cs
public class Context1: IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public DbSet<ItemOld> Items { get; set; }
    // ...
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<ItemOld>().ToTable("Items", "zone1");
        //...
    }
}
```

and similar in `Context2` for `ItemNew` and `zone2`.

If I want to make a change on the `ItemOld` class (e.g. add a property), in Package Manager Console I do something like:

```
Add-Migration AddedSomeProperty -Context Context1 -o MigrationsContext1
```

This adds a migration in my folder as expected, and creates the `Context1ContextModelSnapshot.cs` file in that same folder.

I run `Update-Database -Context Context1` to update my database.

But then, if I change something on the `ItemNew` class and try to do:

```
Add-Migration AddedSomePropertyOnItemNew -Context Context2 -o MigrationsContext2
```

EF Core will (as per my understanding and my situation):

1. Look at the existing `ContextModelSnapshot` **for that context**
2. Find all the differences from the current database to the info in the current `ContextModelSnapshot`
3. Create the migration

Hence, it will also pull the code needed to add a property to `ItemOld`, as the fact that it was already added was not available in the `Context2ContextModelSnapshot`.

So, basically, I have a `ContextModelSnapshot` for each context and they differ if I add migrations to each context.

An idea would be to have both contexts use the same `ContextModelSnapshot`, but I could not find a way to configure this - is there a way to do that?

Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Please close me down if the question is a bit vague, or let me know if I need to provide additional information.

Comment: The implementation of `IMigrationsAssembly` https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/release/7.0/src/EFCore.Relational/Migrations/Internal/MigrationsAssembly.cs filters based on `[DbContext]` attributes. You could replace this service. You can also have the same table in multiple models, and `.ExcludeFromMigrations` for all but one of them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038924/how-to-exclude-one-table-from-automatic-code-first-migrations-in-the-entity-fram

Comment: @JeremyLakeman replacing `IMigrationsAssembly` could technically do the trick, but even EF Core advises not to do so. Regarding `.ExcludeFromMigrations`, I don't think this can help me.

Comment: From your question; "Hence, it will also pull the code needed to add a property to ItemOld" This can only happen if `Context2` has that property in its model, and that class is not excluded. In other words, each table of your database should only be modified by the migrations for a single context.