# EF Core multiple DB contexts and relationships between them

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I wanted to split that notification feature into a separate Class Library project and have a separate DB context. Multiple EF Core DB contexts should be [just fine](https://www.milanjovanovic.tech/blog/using-multiple-ef-core-dbcontext-in-single-application). The problem is that my entities in `NotificationDbContext` depend on the `Employee` table that comes from `AppDbContext`. They have relationships between them. That's why I inherit NotificationDbContext from AppDbContext but the real problem is when I run `dotnet ef database update  --project ... --startup-project ... --context NotificationDbContext`.

> There is already an object named 'Transactions.ContractSequence' in the database.

That's kinda normal, because it's trying to run the migration scripts of both contexts because of the inheritance. How can I deal with it?

```cs
public sealed class NotificationDbContext : AppDbContext
{
    public NotificationDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options, ITenancyContext<ApplicationTenant> tenancyContext, ILogger<AppDbContext> logger, CurrentUser userEmail) 
        : base(options, tenancyContext, logger, userEmail)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<EventType> EventTypes => Set<EventType>();
    public DbSet<Sound> Sounds => Set<Sound>();
    public DbSet<Notification> Notifications => Set<Notification>();
    public DbSet<UserNotificationSettings> UserNotificationSettings => Set<UserNotificationSettings>();
    public DbSet<GlobalNotificationSettings> GlobalNotificationSettings => Set<GlobalNotificationSettings>();
    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        var targetEntityTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
            .Where(t => typeof(ITenantable).IsAssignableFrom(t) && t is { IsClass: true, IsAbstract: false })
            .ToList();
        
        foreach (var entityType in targetEntityTypes)
        {
            modelBuilder.HasTenancy(entityType, () => TenantId, TenancyModelState, hasIndex: false);
        }
        
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }
}
```

```cs
public class AppDbContext : DbContext, ITenantDbContext<ApplicationTenant, Guid>
{
    static TenancyModelState<Guid> _tenancyModelState;
    readonly ITenancyContext<ApplicationTenant> _tenancyContext;
    readonly ILogger _logger;
    readonly string _userEmail;

    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options, ITenancyContext<ApplicationTenant> tenancyContext, ILogger<AppDbContext> logger, CurrentUser userEmail)
        : base(options)
    {
        _tenancyContext = tenancyContext;
        _userEmail = userEmail?.Email ?? CurrentUser.InternalUser;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Guid TenantId => _tenancyContext.Tenant.Id;
    public static TenancyModelState<Guid> TenancyModelState => _tenancyModelState;
    
    public DbSet<ApplicationTenant> Tenants { get; set; }
    public DbSet<InstrumentView> InstrumentView { get; set; }
    public DbSet<vwNoAdminEmployees> NoAdminEmployees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TenantView> TenantView { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LocalMonitoredSymbols> LocalMonitoredSymbolsView { get; set; }
    public DbSet<GlobexSchedule> GlobexSchedules { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        var tenantStoreOptions = new TenantStoreOptions();
        modelBuilder.ConfigureTenantContext<ApplicationTenant, Guid>(tenantStoreOptions);

        // Add multi-tenancy support to model.
        var tenantReferenceOptions = new TenantReferenceOptions();
        modelBuilder.HasTenancy(tenantReferenceOptions, out _tenancyModelState);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationTenant>(b =>
        {
            b.Property(t => t.DisplayName).HasMaxLength(256);
        });

        modelBuilder.HasSequence<int>("ContractSequence", "Transactions")
            .StartsAt(1000)
            .IncrementsBy(1);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationTenant>().ToTable("Tenant", "Security");
    
        var targetEntityTypes = typeof(ITenantable).Assembly.GetTypes()
            .Where(t => typeof(ITenantable).IsAssignableFrom(t) && t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract)
            .ToList();
        
        foreach (var entityType in targetEntityTypes)
        {
            modelBuilder.HasTenancy(entityType, () => _tenancyContext.Tenant.Id, _tenancyModelState, hasIndex: false);
        }
        
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }
    
    public override int SaveChanges(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
    {
        // Ensure multi-tenancy for all tenantable entities.
        this.EnsureTenancy(_tenancyContext?.Tenant?.Id, _tenancyModelState, _logger);
        return base.SaveChanges(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess);
    }

    void SaveAuthInfo()
    {
        // get entries that are being Added or Updated to add the created and updated information
        var modifiedEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified).ToList();
        for (var i = modifiedEntries.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            var entry = modifiedEntries[i];
            if (entry.Entity is not Entity entity) continue;
            if (entry.Entity is not IAuditable)
            {
                if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
                {
                    entity.CreateEntity(_userEmail);
                }

                continue;
            }

            if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                entity.CreateEntity(_userEmail);
            }
            else if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
            {
                entity.UpdateEntity(_userEmail);
            }
        }
    }

    public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        SaveAuthInfo();
        // Ensure multi-tenancy for all tenantable entities.
        this.EnsureTenancy(_tenancyContext?.Tenant?.Id, _tenancyModelState, _logger);
        return base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        SaveAuthInfo();
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    public DbConnection GetDbConnection() => Database.GetDbConnection();

    public async Task ExecuteSpAndRead(string sql, IList<IDataParameter> parameters, Action<IDataReader> fnItem)
    {
        var dbConnection = Database.GetDbConnection();
        await dbConnection.OpenAsync();
        
        using IDbCommand command = dbConnection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = sql;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        if (parameters != null)
        {
            foreach (var param in parameters)
            {
                command.Parameters.Add(param);
            }
        }

        using var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            fnItem(reader);
        }
    }

    public async Task ExecuteQueryAndRead(string sql, IList<IDataParameter> parameters, Action<IDataReader> fnItem)
    {
        var dbConnection = Database.GetDbConnection();
        await dbConnection.OpenAsync();

        using IDbCommand command = dbConnection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = sql;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        if (parameters != null)
        {
            foreach (var param in parameters)
            {
                command.Parameters.Add(param);
            }
        }

        using var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            fnItem(reader);
        }
    }

    public async Task ExecuteQuery(string sql, IList<IDataParameter> parameters)
    {
        await using var dbConnection = Database.GetDbConnection();
        await dbConnection.OpenAsync();
        
        using IDbCommand command = dbConnection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = sql;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        if (parameters != null)
        {
            foreach (var param in parameters)
            {
                command.Parameters.Add(param);
            }
        }

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: When using bounded contexts and considering Migrations then only one DbContext definition should be Code-First while the others are set up for DB-First. (No migrations) If you want each DbContext to be responsible for migrations of particular tables then you may be able to exclude specific entities from migration via `ExcludeFromMigrations` (EF Core 5+): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038924/how-to-exclude-one-table-from-automatic-code-first-migrations-in-the-entity-fram