# Can I create the ADO.NET Entity Framework in C# not delete manually added tables?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a project with ADO.NET Entity Framework in C# and I need it not to delete the manually created tables in the database. When I run the project, I always get deleted tables that were added directly to the SQL database.

Is there a way to prevent those tables from being deleted?

Comment: Tag the EF version? Mine doesn't delete any tables, post the code where this is triggered.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038924/how-to-exclude-one-table-from-automatic-code-first-migrations-in-the-entity-fram